# Datagridview celltype to checkbox

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview, checkbox

In my datbase(mysql) i a have a certain table that containts a column with/ zero's and one's, 
When i load this into my table and append this table to my datagridview i get a nice column with one's and zero's.

No problem there.
But i want to change the column type to checkbox column but i have no idea how to do that.

I have tried to change to column datatype of my datatable, also i tried to change the column type of my datagriview mut nothing seems to work...

Iam using C#.net and Mysql

Can anyone please advice me in this matter?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` to your `DataGridView`: Properties-Columns. Then in properties of that column you can set `FalseValue` to 0 for example and `TrueValue` to 1. You can do all that in VS designer.

Comment: Thats not gonna work because i have a datasource attached to the datagridview

Comment: @WillemT Why is that a problem? You can set DataPropertyName of that column too.

Comment: But i dont want to add a column i want to change a current column
EDIT: sorry i didnt know you could do that Iam trying it right now

Comment: @WillemT Then change it. ColumnType property allows you to do that.

Comment: but can i just enter the column name of the table into the datapropertyname?

Comment: @WillemT Well, what did you set? Did you set FalseValue and TrueValue? You should be able to select PropertyName if your DataSource is set in the designer. Otherwise, typing a property name will do.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was specifing the wrong property name.